# When I deploy Deploy orbeon Proxy-Portlet in Liferay, the deplay fails with the error: The moduleId /proxy-portlet/6.1.1/war is not correct

Tags: liferay, orbeon

I did sign up for a Trial Registration of Orbeon Forms PE and wanted to evaluate the Liferay Integration Features. 
I am trying to Install: 
orbeon-4.8.1.201502021959-PE
in a 
Liferay 6.1 GA2 installation with Tomcat 7

Installation of orbeon.war went fine, but when I try to Install the proxy-portlet, the following Stack shows up:

```
 com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.hot.HotDeployException: Error registering plugins for proxy-portlet
com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.hot.HotDeployException: Error registering plugins for proxy-portlet
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.hot.BaseHotDeployListener.throwHotDeployException(BaseHotDeployListener.java:46)
        at com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.PluginPackageHotDeployListener.invokeDeploy(PluginPackageHotDeployListener.java:62)
        at com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.HotDeployImpl.doFireDeployEvent(HotDeployImpl.java:188)
        at com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.HotDeployImpl.fireDeployEvent(HotDeployImpl.java:96)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.hot.HotDeployUtil.fireDeployEvent(HotDeployUtil.java:27)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PluginContextListener.fireDeployEvent(PluginContextListener.java:151)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PluginContextListener.doPortalInit(PluginContextListener.java:141)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.BasePortalLifecycle.portalInit(BasePortalLifecycle.java:42)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.PortalLifecycleUtil.flushInits(PortalLifecycleUtil.java:48)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.initPlugins(MainServlet.java:849)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.init(MainServlet.java:357)
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1266)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1185)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1080)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5027)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5314)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:618)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1100)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1618)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: The moduleId /proxy-portlet/6.1.1/war is not correct
        at com.liferay.portal.plugin.ModuleId.(ModuleId.java:128)
        at com.liferay.portal.plugin.ModuleId.getInstance(ModuleId.java:35)
        at com.liferay.portal.plugin.PluginPackageImpl.(PluginPackageImpl.java:62)
        at com.liferay.portal.plugin.PluginPackageUtil._readPluginPackageProperties(PluginPackageUtil.java:995)
        at com.liferay.portal.plugin.PluginPackageUtil._readPluginPackageServletContext(PluginPackageUtil.java:1065)
        at com.liferay.portal.plugin.PluginPackageUtil.readPluginPackageServletContext(PluginPackageUtil.java:210)
        at com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.PluginPackageHotDeployListener.doInvokeDeploy(PluginPackageHotDeployListener.java:99)
        at com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.PluginPackageHotDeployListener.invokeDeploy(PluginPackageHotDeployListener.java:59)
        ... 27 more
```

However, I looked in the liferay-plugin-packages.properties and amde the entry for the moduleId. 
The first error disappears, but when I try to put the Orbeon Forms portlet on a page, another errors shows up:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: The requested resource (/proxy-portlet/orbeonformsproxyportlet/invoke) is not available
    at org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet.serveResource(DefaultServlet.java:776)
    at org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet.doGet(DefaultServlet.java:411)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:72)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:73)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:690)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:599)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:536)
    at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.invoke(InvokerPortletImpl.java:534)
    at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.invokeRender(InvokerPortletImpl.java:607)
    at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.render(InvokerPortletImpl.java:359)
    at org.apache.jsp.html.portal.render_005fportlet_jsp._jspService(render_005fportlet_jsp.java:1207)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.DirectRequestDispatcher.include(DirectRequestDispatcher.java:97)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.PACLRequestDispatcherWrapper.doDispatch(PACLRequestDispatcherWrapper.java:90)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.PACLRequestDispatcherWrapper.include(PACLRequestDispatcherWrapper.java:54)
    at com.liferay.portal.util.PortalImpl.renderPortlet(PortalImpl.java:5158)
    at com.liferay.portal.util.PortalUtil.renderPortlet(PortalUtil.java:1569)
    at com.liferay.portlet.layoutconfiguration.util.RuntimePortletImpl.processPortlet(RuntimePortletImpl.java:165)
    at com.liferay.portlet.layoutconfiguration.util.RuntimePortletImpl.processPortlet(RuntimePortletImpl.java:97)
    at com.liferay.portlet.layoutconfiguration.util.RuntimePortletImpl.doProcessTemplate(RuntimePortletImpl.java:531)
    at com.liferay.portlet.layoutconfiguration.util.RuntimePortletImpl.doDispatch(RuntimePortletImpl.java:394)
    at com.liferay.portlet.layoutconfiguration.util.RuntimePortletImpl.processTemplate(RuntimePortletImpl.java:228)
    at com.liferay.portlet.layoutconfiguration.util.RuntimePortletImpl.processTemplate(RuntimePortletImpl.java:216)
    at com.liferay.portlet.layoutconfiguration.util.RuntimePortletUtil.processTemplate(RuntimePortletUtil.java:113)
    at org.apache.jsp.html.portal.layout.view.portlet_jsp._jspService(portlet_jsp.java:507)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:72)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:73)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:690)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:599)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:536)
    at com.liferay.portal.action.LayoutAction.includeLayoutContent(LayoutAction.java:468)
    at com.liferay.portal.action.LayoutAction.processLayout(LayoutAction.java:735)
    at com.liferay.portal.action.LayoutAction.execute(LayoutAction.java:249)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:431)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:236)
    at com.liferay.portal.struts.PortalRequestProcessor.process(PortalRequestProcessor.java:176)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1196)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:414)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.callParentService(MainServlet.java:551)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.service(MainServlet.java:528)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:72)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:163)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.secure.SecureFilter.processFilter(SecureFilter.java:294)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:57)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:108)
    at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:202)
    at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:180)
    at net.bull.javamelody.PluginMonitoringFilter.doFilter(PluginMonitoringFilter.java:85)
    at net.bull.javamelody.LiferayMonitoringFilter.doFilter(LiferayMonitoringFilter.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor556.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.bean.ClassLoaderBeanHandler.invoke(ClassLoaderBeanHandler.java:67)
    at $Proxy885.doFilter(Unknown Source)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:108)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:73)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:690)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:477)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:402)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:329)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.FriendlyURLServlet.service(FriendlyURLServlet.java:138)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:72)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:163)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.strip.StripFilter.processFilter(StripFilter.java:335)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:57)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:108)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:163)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.gzip.GZipFilter.processFilter(GZipFilter.java:123)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:57)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:108)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:163)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.secure.SecureFilter.processFilter(SecureFilter.java:294)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:57)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:108)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:163)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.i18n.I18nFilter.processFilter(I18nFilter.java:241)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:57)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:108)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:163)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.etag.ETagFilter.processFilter(ETagFilter.java:56)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:57)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:108)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:163)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.autologin.AutoLoginFilter.processFilter(AutoLoginFilter.java:246)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:57)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:108)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:163)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.sso.ntlm.NtlmPostFilter.processFilter(NtlmPostFilter.java:83)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:57)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:108)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:163)
    at com.liferay.portal.sharepoint.SharepointFilter.processFilter(SharepointFilter.java:80)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:57)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:108)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:163)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.virtualhost.VirtualHostFilter.processFilter(VirtualHostFilter.java:216)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:57)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:108)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:187)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:95)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:738)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:108)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:167)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:95)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:167)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:95)
    at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:202)
    at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:180)
    at net.bull.javamelody.PluginMonitoringFilter.doFilter(PluginMonitoringFilter.java:85)
    at net.bull.javamelody.LiferayMonitoringFilter.doFilter(LiferayMonitoringFilter.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor556.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.bean.ClassLoaderBeanHandler.invoke(ClassLoaderBeanHandler.java:67)
    at $Proxy885.doFilter(Unknown Source)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:108)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:187)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:95)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:73)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1001)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Any Help would be really appreciated.

Comment: The first error seems to be of no consequence: even if I get this error, the portlet deploys fine. But out of curiosity, what did you add to `liferay-plugin-packages.properties`?

Comment: What about the 2nd error? Do you see the portlet deployed anyway, or did deployment fail?

Comment: Deployment seems to be succesfull, but when I put the FormRunner on any Liferay page, the 2.nd error occurs.
As for you question about the properties:
`name=Proxy-portlet-Orbeon
module-group-id=liferay
module-incremental-version=1
tags=
short-description=
change-log=
page-url=
author=
licenses=`

Comment: Thanks re. properties. If you place the portlet on a page, and configure it to point to a Form Runner form, does this still happen?

Comment: I Can not access the Preferences of the portlet. Same error occurs. POrtlet tell me it is not available, and the stack shows the java.io.FileNotFoundException: The requested resource (/proxy-portlet/orbeonformsproxyportlet/invoke) is not available

Comment: I have followed up in the [forum thread](http://discuss.orbeon.com/When-I-deploy-Deploy-orbeon-Proxy-Portlet-in-Liferay-the-deplay-fails-with-the-error-The-moduleId-td4659692.html).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem on a theme written on Liferay 6.2 plugins SDK. The problem was that in `liferay-plugin-package.properties` there was the following line:

```
module-group-id=
```

**`module-group-id` cannot be empty** and its value must not contain slash `/`. I changed the line in the following way:

```
module-group-id=liferay
```

It resolved the problem. Indeed, it was a [Liferay bug](https://issues.liferay.com/browse/IDE-1400) that had been resolved in newer versions.